# 'Companies' vs 'Businesses' label

Tags: information-architecture

The goal of the website is to get business owners and their managers to sign up and invite their employees to join.

The users are probably over 30, living in the United States. These are the types of companies that hire low-skill employees, such as McDonalds, a coffee shop, or a cleaning service.

For those of you familiar with information architecture, which navigation menu label is more appropriate? Companies or Businesses?

When I describe what it is (see first sentence), I use "business." When I read a usability website, I see "companies" unless they're talking about the act of business, such as "improving business results." This link is for both business owners and managers, so perhaps "Management" may be appropriate.

Thanks for your help!

Edit: I also naturally say "These are the types of **companies** . . ." when describing it. It's really a toss up.

Comment: You may wish to investigate and "open card sort" exercise with prospective users. http://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/card-sorting.html

Comment: ... or, more to the point, run a "card sort like" exercise with the type of information that is inside the navigation menu you are looking at. The users will then name the category appropriately.

Comment: Nice! So include both labels and ask people to define their own headings.

Comment: Possibly - we might be saying the same thing, but in different ways. A "card sort" has participants take a set of terms and categorize them -- and "open sort" lets participants name their own categories, a "closed sort" the categories are defined. So, you could take the *terms* that exist under the categories you are asking about and have the participant name that category, or take both "company" and "business" and have them put terms under each (maybe they'd do all one, maybe split them). You might even find that "Corporation" is the preferred. :)

Comment: Now that I've used you as a sounding board, I'm thinking the right label might be "Manage."

Comment: "Manage" is a very actionable term and has strong drive behind it. I like it! Hopefully the users do too. :)

Answer (score 2):

Manage is a verb, though, and one that does not really say "The goal of the website is to get business owners and their managers to sign up and invite their employees to join." *Manage* also has distinctly negative connotations, especially to employees (your target market). Since you are trying to encourage employee participation, I don't think this is the best choice.

Business is usually used to connote smaller organizations, though, so is not be the best term. Out of the three choices you have given, I think "company" is most appropriate, but think there probably is a better term still.

---

Sometimes boiling things down to their essence produces the best design solutions. So, really, what you are trying to do is encourage engagement throughout an organization, right? Engagement, therefore, should be the actionable term, not organization. So in this line of thought, I think something along the lines of:

- Community, or ("Business Name") Community

Would be the best solution.

Comment: Agreed.  A business can be just one person.  A company is usually a larger kind of business (often a limited liability company, ie an entity in its own right)